# Yamaha HS7 sounds odd

Tags: speakers, music, cable, studio-monitors, loudspeakers

A month ago, I bought a “Like New” Yamaha HS7 off eBay.

I didn't have a cable to connect these to my computer until today, when I got a 1/8 inch to dual XLR cable and connected them to my computer.

I noticed that the monitors sound extremely different; one of them sounds relatively normal, maybe slightly trebly, while the other has next to no high end, sounds very muffled, and is significantly lower in volume as well.
I found out later that the XLR output end of the cable is unbalanced so that may be a source of issue, however even when I made the signal mono and used the same output, one of the speakers is always quieter and more muffled than the other.

I've tried different combinations of mixing inputs/power cables/power source, but got the same result, which leads me to believe it's not the cable.

Does this mean that this speaker is faulty, or could this be somehow caused by the unbalanced cable?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have done most of the right things for testing…
Mono signal, swap cables, swap speakers etc

One last test - hold the palm of your hand over each tweeter & see if it gets duller or stays the same. Separate the speakers or test one at a time to double-check.
If one of the HF units has failed, that's the simplest test.

Also - make sure the room & HF trim controls on the rear are working as expected. [I've never used these particular speakers, so idk what effect that should have, but make sure both have the same effect as each other.]

[image]

It's a bi-amped system, so would probably cost more to have a professional diagnose it that they're worth. If you can, send them back.

Comment: I did your test. The faulty speaker is much less impacted by the palm blocking the HF tweeter, so it is very likely a faulty HF tweeter. The only difference I hear when blocking it is the lack of the hi-hat, while on the functional speaker the highs in general get muffled. The controls seem to work fine. I assume this means something is wrong with the HF tweeter or the wiring of it?

Comment: Yup - driver or circuitry. 'Quick' test for which is to swap the drivers, which will eliminate either driver or electronics. Drivers are not very expensive - I found this https://www.proaudioservice.co.uk/product/yamaha-hs7-tweeter-hf-driver-ye743a00/ but a pro would charge you at least $£€ 60 to even open it up.